# MimeType errado ao enviar imagem para o S3 com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando Laravel 5.3 e enviando imagens para o S3 da Amazon.

Já coloquei as regras no bucket para que ele seja público e estou enviando a imagem da seguinte forma:

```
request()->file('avatar')->storeAs('uploads/143', 'avatar.jpg', 's3');
```

O arquivo está sendo enviado normalmente para o S3 porém não envia com o mimetype correto. No exemplo acima o mimetype do arquivo seria `image/jpeg` mas ao ver direto pelo painel da Amazon S3 o arquivo está com mimetype `application/octet-stream`

Isso faz o arquivo, ao ser acessado, abrir a janela de salvar (download) do navegador e não exibe simplesmente o arquivo como esperado.

Não achei uma forma de definir o mimetype ou corrigir isso nas configurações do bucket.

Comment: Tá parecendo que não é problema do Laravel "enviar o mime" errado, e sim da resposta que você recebe do amazon está com esse header.

Comment: Jà tentou fazer o teste, antes do upload, `request()->file('avatar')->getClientMimeType()`?

Comment: Já sim, no Laravel está exibindo com MimeType certo. Então eu envio e vou no console da amazon para clicar e ver a imagem no navegador mas ai ela abre para download.

Comment: Então realmente, parece ser configuração na amazon

Comment: Se eu envio o arquivo direto pelo console da amazon o mimetype fica normal (image/jpeg) mas pelo Laravel não.

Comment: Você poderia abrir um issue no Github relatando esse problema!  https://github.com/laravel/laravel